# Android Toolbar and Menu are driving me crazy

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-menu

I've made a Toolbar in the Activity xml file (snipped for brevity)

```
<Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:title="@string/password_manager"
    android:logo="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

I did try other flavors of toolbar - androidx.appcompat..., ...appbar.MaterialToolbar, and the one I came across the most often android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar. These crash my app.

I made a menu xml that has this (snipped for brevity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/hmenu_createnew"
        android:checkable="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/create_new"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

At this point everything looked and worked fine. Now - I want to dynamically control the menu items. I added the override:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu( menu );
    this.menu = menu;
    return true;
}
```

And here's where it's gotten frustrating. The above override was not called. I did a ton of searching and came across one person who suggested a change to the Activity class declaration.

He said instead of 'Extends Activity' change to 'Extends AppCompatActivity'

I checked my class declaration and it already **was** AppCompat. On a whim I changed it to Activity.

With this change I can see now in debugger my override is getting called. Yeay!

But my menu is nowhere to be found!.

In my activity.class are these few lines (snipped for brevity):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mytoolbar);
        setActionBar( toolbar );
        toolbar.inflateMenu( R.menu.home_mainmenu );

}
```

Since that no longer worked I removed toolbar.inflateMenu(), replaced it with getMenuInflater() and put it in the override, as below.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu );
    getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.home_mainmenu, menu );
    return false;
}
```

No joy.

I also tried this:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu( menu );
    getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.home_mainmenu, menu );
    this.menu = menu;
    return false;
}
```

Still no joy.

In the two overrides above I also tried substituting getMenuInflater.... for toolbar.inflateMenu...

No joy.

What I want is a regular toolbar with a right justified standard button with the three vertical dots that displays a menu when clicked.

At this point I am clueless so let me close by saying THANK YOU in advance to the angel out there who has the solution.

Does anyone else think this is needlessly difficult?..... Again, TIA.

Comment: please give your question a valid title in future, this doesn't help anyone to understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: yes, the title should depict question without using unnecessary info.

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest applying `androidX` migration. So `Toolbar` package will be
   `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` and for parent activity `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`
2. Make sure that the Activity theme is not inherited from `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`
3. use `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` method not `setActionBar` in `onCreate` or inside overridden `setContentView` method
4. Inflate custom menu **before** `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)`:

   ```
   override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
       menuInflater.inflate(/*menu res id*/)
       this.menu = menu;
       return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
   }
   ```

   With such setup it should work

Answer (score 0):

Well I eventually did figure it out. To repeat a bit, I am using this library:

import android.widget.Toolbar;

because I want to use Activity - not AppCompatActivity

so the xml declaration looks like this: `<Toolbar ..... />`

Because we are using Toolbar we must remove the default ActionBar that Android gives us. This requires an edit of the app manifest.
Anywhere you find "AppTheme.ActionBar" change to "AppTheme.NoActionBar"

in the java class I have this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mytoolbar);
        setActionBar( toolbar );
}
```

Note the use of 'setActionBar' as opposed to 'setSupportActionBar'. That is correct.

Then there is the (finally!) properly coded override which might be informative to anyone regardless of what import library you choose:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu( menu );
        if ( !bMenuInitialized ) {
            this.menu = menu;
            getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.home_mainmenu, menu );
            bMenuInitialized = true;
        }
        /*
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        toolbar.inflateMenu( R.menu.home_mainmenu );
         */
        return true;
    }
```

I left in the commented block what NOT to do. Calling invalidateOptionsMenu(), which you will see all over the internet, causes an infinite loop. Do not do that..... Only call invalidateOptionsMenu from some other code block if you have altered the menu in some way. This is the reason why the toolbar was not showing itself. (By 'altering the menu' I don't mean setting attributes on MenuItems.)

I also learned that you MUST create a flag to indicate if the menu has been inflated yet, because the onPrepareOptionsMenu() gets called every time the user accesses the toolbar. You don't want to keep inflating your menu every time because it just adds to the menu that's already in it making it longer and longer.

There you have it. I hope this helps someone. And thank you to all who responded.